# Which one is better to be used at Http server, Casbah or ReactiveMongo?

Tags: mongodb, scala, casbah, reactivemongo

I want to start a MongoDB database for my project and I'm a Scala user, but I couldn't find a good comparison between these two Scala frameworks for MongoDB, what are their main differences, supports and other aspects?

Answer (score 2):

Well, ReactiveMongo by design is "reactive" so everything happens asynchronously and you can continue with normal flow of execution. ReactiveMongo also has macros that do `BSON <--> Scala Case Class` conversion.

Casbah on the other is **the** officially supported Scala binding for MongoDB, so it essentially supports **all** the MongoDB operators.

Now if you really want to do some fancy queries on MongoDB, you may find yourself at home with Casbah, but with ReactiveMongo that is not the case.

Also note that ReactiveMongo integrates very well with Play framework.

Comment: Note that using the `RawCommand` of the about-to-be-released ReactiveMongo 0.11, you can do the fancy queries which are not specifically implemented in the API, still in a reactive way.

Comment: @cchantep that's good to know. can you share any sample link ?

Comment: http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11.0/documentation/advanced-topics/commands.html

Comment: @cchantep, the simple Count example at the beginning of your link seems to refer to the "old way", and gives a deprecation warning when used. Is there a simple way to count without going to the rawCommand described later in the document?

Comment: For count try `reactivemongo.api.commands.Count`. About the doc, the last example is using `rawCommand`.

Comment: @cchantep The link is broken. 
For someone like me who really concern using native mongo query syntax, check the below link

http://reactivemongo.org/releases/0.11/documentation/advanced-topics/commands.html

Comment: @tuxdna can we use casbah for Async calls?